# Consecutive Job Execution in Hudson

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

We are using Hudson for our builds and deploys. Currently we have four main jobs: BUILD, DEPLOY-DEV, DEPLOY-TEST, and DEPLOY-PROD.

The BUILD job is parameterized, so we can assign new version numbers and augment them with the BUILD_NUMBER managed by Hudson. This works very well. We also have a "nightlybuild" parameter that defaults to false. Our intention is to only set this via another Hudson job.

We are trying to have an automated NIGHTLY-BUILD job that first calls our BUILD job with the "nightlybuild" parameter set and once that is successful, call the DEPLOY-DEV job. We also want to call out to a SONAR job to analyze the code, but for this question, the 2-step solution is sufficient.

For the NIGHTLY-BUILD job, the only way to call a parameterized job that I can figure out is the post-build action of "Trigger parameterized build on other projects". I can't trigger off of the BUILD job directly because the "nightlybuild" default is false and I also don't want to trigger off any manula builds. I also have a NIGHTLY-DEPLOY that has a build trigger of "Build after other projects are built" on NIGHTLY-BUILD. Since these are both ultimately post build actions they trigger at the same time instead of consecutively.

```
Started by user anonymous
Triggering a new build of BUILD #49
Triggering a new build of NIGHTLY-DEPLOY #3
Triggering a new build of NIGHTTY-SONAR #3
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update; build not configured with trigger: NIGHTLY-BUILD #5
Finished: SUCCESS
```

When I start the build, it completes in a few seconds and starts the BUILD and DEPLOY concurrently, so as a new version is building, the old version is deploying. Not what I want.

I looked at and downloaded the "[Build Pipeline Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Build+Pipeline+Plugin)", but it looks like it just relies on the same post build actions for the automatic transitions and adds new functionality for manual transitions.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use Parameterized Trigger plugin as a *build step*, not post-build step. Then it has an option to wait for the downstream build to complete.

Note: this works with Jenkins, I can't guarantee that this option exists in the Hudson version of the plugin.

Comment: That makes sense. I kept looking for an actual Build step to call another build or parameterized build and it is nonexistent. The plugin version on Hudson is 2.4 (almost 2 years old). I have to see what it would take to standup a Jenkins instance on the same box.

Comment: I'm still hoping for a Hudson based solution

Comment: Corporate restrictions that do not let you use Jenkins?

Comment: There are no corporate restrictions, just bandwidth restrictions and a general concern that updating the CI server from Hudson to Jenkins would cause builds to break and potentially impact schedules. We actually tried to setup Jenkins side by side with Hudson and that made a huge mess. Once the dust settles, I'm going to install a separate Tomcat instance and load Jenkins there and try migrating a project or two over at a time.

Comment: Bandwidth restrictions was referring to people bandwidth and not any technical server restrictions. :-)